# Symfony 5.2 Form CollectionType not rendering embedded form fields in their order

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Symfony 5.2.1

Embedded form is not rendering the fields by its defined order in the form type builder.

This is my view

```
{{ form_widget(form.surfaces) }}
```

This is included in the parent form type

```
->add('surfaces', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => SurfaceType::class,
    'label' => false,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
])
```

And this in the child form (embedded form collection)

```
->add('description', null)
->add('value', null)
```

Symfony is rendering the field value before the description

Can somebody help !!

Comment: Then what about reversing the order of description and value ?

Comment: @DylanKas I updated the question. It's not working